# Database updating wrong data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

I am currently working on a fun project, which involves Ajax, HTML, JavaScript, PHP and SQL.

I have debugged my project as far as I could, and I am 100% sure my AJAX, HTML and JavaScript are working fine and my variables are send to the server correctly.

I am trying to fetch data from the database, subtract a number (submitted in the form) from this data and update the database accordingly.

My database **does** update. However, it is not displaying the correct numbers. When submitting `1` in the form, it will ALWAYS return the same numbers in the database. (Which is odd, because I am subtracting it...). I am 100% sure the data from the form is passed to the server correctly, so I would like you all to check my server file, which should be the problem.

**Edit:**
The database connection is made in `db.php` and is made correctly. This has been tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to switch to prepared statements to fix your sql injection problems.

Apart from that, what's wrong with this specific code, is that [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does not return a number, it returns a resource. You need to fetch a row to get the number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaking the return value of `mysql_query`, look [php's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

`mysql_query` returns a *resource* which then may be passed to some other funcion to extract the value returned by the query you made. You should do something like this:

```
$res = mysql_query(...)
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)
$dec = $res["column_name"] - $some_value
```

You should check the $_REQUEST[...] array values to eliminate [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, `mysql_query` returns `resource`, not result itself. So you have to modify your code to something like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("your_query_here");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$totaalaantal = $row[0];
```

check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php